# Generics to generalize WebRequests and parsing into custom objects in C#

Tags: c#, generics, parameters, mono

A bit of a architectural question. I am doing a lot of WebRequest:s in C# (Mono). Here's an example how one method that fetches "WorkFlowSchemes" are declared:

```
public void GetWorkFlowSchemes(
   Credientials credentials, 
   ServerDelegates.WorkFlowSchemesSuccessDelegate successDelegate, 
   ServerDelegates.ErrorDelegate errorDelegate)
```

Which then have "hardcoded" values for which url to fetch from, which callback the response it calling and in that callback: which type to parse to.

I would like to make this method generic to not having to write X number of methods all very similar for each type of call I make. Instead I would like something like this:

```
public void GetCustomPath<K>(
    Credientials credentials,
    Path pathToFetch,
    ServerDelegate<K>.SuccessDelegate successDelegate, //Generic delegate to return different types of parsed result
    ServerDelegates.ErrorDelegate errorDelegate) // no need to be generic
```

where K is the type of the delegate to return i.e. `WorkFlowScemes` or WorkFlow.

This work compiles fairly well, until the parsing. Previously I parsed it by doing this:

```
List<WorkFlowScheme> workFlowSchemeList = serverXmlParser.parseXmlToWorkFlowSchemeList(responseBody);
```

yet another hardcoded parsing method for WorkFlowList I would prefer to generalize. The `parseXmlToWorkFlowSchemeList` looks like this:

```
    public List<WorkFlowScheme> parseXmlToWorkFlowSchemeList (string xml)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        List<WorkFlowScheme> result = 
            (
                from x in doc.Element("workflowschemeList").Elements("workflowscheme")
                select new WorkFlowScheme().Setup(x)
                ).ToList();
        return result;
    }
```

`where .Setup(x)` is a help method stored in each type to convert and store the XElement values into strings in the current object. Here is where I got stuck. First I tried to make a generic method:

```
public List<T> parseXmlToCustomObject<T> (string xml, String root, String key)
{
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        List<T> result = 
            (
                from x in doc.Element(root).Elements(key)
                select new T().Setup(x)
                ).ToList();
        return result;
}
```

"select new T.Setup(x)" does not work

- First since I cannot create "`new T()`" (Edit: already solved)
- Secondly cause the compiler wont know where to find the Setup method

Any suggestions?

I have also considered making all my objects to parse to a subclass of a "ServerObject" to more easy be able to call .Setup, but can't figure out how to merge that with generics.

Edit: Here's what I got so far:

```
public void GetCustomListObject<T>(Account account, String path, RequestStateGen<List<T>>.SuccessDelegate successDelegate, ServerDelegates.ErrorDelegate errorDelegate)
        where T : ServerObject, new()
    {
        var request = getGetRequest(account, path);

        RequestStateGen<List<T>> state = new RequestStateGen<List<T>>();
        state.Request = request;

        IAsyncResult result =
            request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(onGetWorkFlowSchemes), state);

        //setupTimeOut(result, state);
        string responseBody = extractResponseAndCallDelegateOnError(request, result, errorDelegate);
        if (responseBody != null)
        {
            List<T> parsedObject = serverXmlParser.parseXmlToCustomObject<T>(responseBody);
            if (parsedObject != null)
            {
                successDelegate(parsedObject);
            }
        }
    }
```

And parsing method:

```
public List<T> parseXmlToCustomObject<T> (string xml)
        where T : ServerObject, new()
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        List<T> result = 
            (
                from x in doc.Element("workflowschemeList").Elements("workflowscheme")
                select new T().Setup(x)
                ).ToList();
        return result;
    }
```

Where ServerObject is a baseobject to all my custom object classes containing .Setup. The error I now get is on line "List result = " with error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.List<xxxx.Core.Network.Objects.ServerObject>' to `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all your classes have a public parameterless constructor, you can add the constraint `where T : new()` to the `parseXmlToCustomObject`. This will get rid of the first error.

To get rid of the second error, you will have to create an interface or base class that contains the `Setup` method and make all your classes implement this interface or derive from this base class and add that as another constraint: `where T : ISetupable, new()`. <sub>(Please forgive the name)</sub>

Your method would then look like this:

```
public List<T> parseXmlToCustomObject<T> (string xml, String root, String key)
    where T : ISetupable, new()
{
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        List<T> result = 
            (
                from x in doc.Element(root).Elements(key)
                select new T().Setup(x)
                ).ToList();
        return result;
}
```

If you are unable to ensure that all classes have a public parameterless constructor you will have to resort to factories to create your objects.

Comment: Not used to the select and where keyword. select (where T : ISetupable, new()).Setup(x) does not work. "Unexpected symbol 'where'". Any suggestions?

Comment: @Sunkas: Please see update. The `where` is not part of a query, its a [generic constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. However I now complains on the row of declaring "List<T> parsedObject = serverXmlParser.parseXmlToCustomObject<T>(responseBody);" But compiler complains: "The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method ..... The type 'T' must have a public constructor'

Comment: @Sunkas: The constraints need to be applied to `GetCustomPath` as well.

Comment: Tried to add "where T : ServerObject, new()" to GetCustomListObject<T> but then it complains on "List<T> result = " which complaint: "Cannot simply convert type ...ServerObject to ...List<T>"

Comment: "Cannot simply convert type ...List<ServerObject> to ...List<T>" that is

Comment: @Sunkas: I don't know `GetCustomListObject<T>`, but basically, you need to add the constraints to all methods in the call chain that are generic. For example, if you have `GetCustomPath<K>` calling `Foo<T>` calling `parseXmlToCustomObject<T>`, the constraint needs to be added to all three methods.

Comment: @Sunkas: You might want to add the code for `GetCustomListObject<T>` to your question.

Comment: Don't think it's relevant. What I wanted to say was that I added the constraint to the calling method GetCustonListObject<T> but a new error occured "Cannot simply convert type ...List<ServerObject> to List<T>' on the line of "List<T> result = "

Comment: Where all my objects enherit from ServerObject. Is that the way to go?

Comment: @Sunkas: Yes, that method is relevant, because somewhere in it you are trying to perform that cast. The fact that all objects from `ServerObject` is ok.

Comment: Got it working. Just changed it to "select (T)new T().Setup(x)"

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify a constraint to your generic method in order to make a new instance of `T`

```
public List<T> parseXmlToCustomObject<T> (string xml, String root, String key) where T : new(){
[...]
}
```

**[Edit]**
for your second question: you need to have a base class or interface having the `Setup()` method and another constraint to your generic method:

Let's say you have a base class `BaseClass` having your `Setup()` method:

```
public List<T> parseXmlToCustomObject<T> (string xml, String root, String key) where T : BaseClass, new(){
[...]
}
```

Comment: More information about constraints in generics here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970(v=vs.80).aspx